# I need to set banner ad position right of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with banner ads I want to set the position of banner ad top right of the screen.

I am using `anchorType: AnchorType.top`, but this only allow center-top of the screen but I want to show it `right-top` of the screen but there is no such option `anchorType: AnchorType.right`.

Comment: this is a good tutorial on how to position widgets https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-widget-positioning-guide/

Comment: positioning the widget and positioning the banner ads two different things.